# How can I simplify this redundant React code in the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So I have Material UI Textfields that get some data from an API and here is my code. It works perfectly but I want to simplify it, and I have no idea on how to even do it. I was thinking of using a map, but not sure how to deal with the nested z elements. Any help would be appreciated a lot!

P.S. I am a beginner.

```html
             <div>
              <TextField value={queryCache.getQueryData('x1').y1}/>
              <TextField value={queryCache.getQueryData('x1').y2}/>
              <TextField value={queryCache.getQueryData('x1').y3.z1}/>
              <TextField value={queryCache.getQueryData('x1').y3.z2}/>
              <TextField value={queryCache.getQueryData('x1').y4}/>
              ...
            </div>
```

Comment: You can make a function that return TextField component.Secondly, you can populate the values in an array . You have to then iterate the TextField component with array of the values.

Comment: @AhmadSuddle I am not entirely sure what you mean, could you please show me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Something like `data = queryCache.getQueryData('x1');`, `values = [data.y1, data.y2, data.y3.z1, ...];`, and then `{values.map(value => <TextField value={value} />}`.

Comment: @epsiloneel, Is there any specific pattern for which element we have to get z element ?

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for your answer, it makes total sense, but now I am not sure where to define these values as my `queryCache.getQueryData('x')` is updated async from a mutation hook. Could you please help me with that as well? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure. Can you update your question to include that hook (and component) code so we may more clearly understand the scope of your question? It can likely be computed before the JSX return.

Comment: @DrewReese Hello, thank you for offering to help. I have managed to make it work, by slightly changing the way the code was structured. I have posted my solution and tagged you inside. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the help from @DrewReese I have managed to sort this out, and make it work. Here is the solution for future reference.

I have taken out the logic outside the return() and that helped me create non-redundant code.

```
const data = queryCache.getQueryData("x");
const values = [
  data.y1,
  data.y2.z1,
  data.y2.z2,
  data.y2.z3,
  data.y3,
  data.y4,
......
];
```

And then simply in my return statement for the JSX I have what @DrewReese suggested:

```
{values.map((value) => (
      <TextField value={value} />
    ))}
```

Note: I have changed the values to x/y/z as this is sensitive information that cannot be publicly visible.

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `queryCache.getQueryData('x1')` is a "collection" of sorts, that holds several values accessible from different paths.

What you could do is define the list of those paths and iterate through them, getting the needed values:

```js
const paths = [
  [ "y1" ], // [ "name" ]
  [ "y2" ], // [ "age" ]
  [ "y3", "z1" ], // [ "location", "country" ]
  [ "y3", "z2" ], // [ "location", "city" ]
  [ "y4" ], // [ "occupation" ]
];

function getValue(collection, path) {
  return path.reduce((subCollection, key) => subCollection[key], collection);
}

// Examples:
// getValue({ name: "John" }, [ "name" ])
// => "John"
// getValue({ location: { country: "US", city: "NYC" } }, [ "location", "city" ])
// => "NYC"
```

```js
<div>
  {paths.map((path) => (
    <TextField value={getValue(queryCache.getQueryData('x1')), path} key={path.join(",")} />
  ))}
</div>
```

I'd also suggest a) putting `queryCache.getQueryData('x1')` in a variable and reuse it, rather than recalculating it each time, and b) coming up with a better `key`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
  const coordinates = [
        {
            x: x1,
            y: y1
        },
        {
            x: x2,
            y: y2
        },
        {
            x: x3,
            y: y3,
            z: z1
        },
        {
            x: x4,
            y: y3,
            z: z2
        },
        {
            x: x5,
            y: y4
        },
    ]

    coordinates.map(({x, y, z}) => (
        <TextField value={z ? queryCache.getQueryData(x)[y][z] : queryCache.getQueryData(x)[y] } />
    ))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and the time you took to answer me, but this simply wouldn't work because I would need to hardcode again and it would look the same with the redundancies in a different way.

Comment: Could you please add the structure of your data?